# Сравнить каждое значение словаря с каждым другим значением словаря

Tags: python, list, матрицы, словари

Есть словарь

`{(1190, 135): 77, (1352, 135): 229, (1514, 135): 0, (1676, 135): 59, (1199, 297): 0, (1352, 297): 108, (1514, 297): 109, (1676, 297): 33, (1190, 459): 233, (1352, 459): 108, (1514, 459): 233, (1676, 459): 109, (1190, 621): 77, (1352, 621): 60, (1514, 621): 229, (1676, 621): 72, (1190, 783): 60, (1352, 783): 33, (1514, 783): 24, (1676, 783): 255, (1190, 945): 255, (1352, 945): 24, (1514, 945): 59, (1676, 945): 72}`

Он содержит координаты:

```
coords = [
          [(1190, 135), (1352, 135), (1514, 135), (1676, 135)],
          [(1199, 297), (1352, 297), (1514, 297), (1676, 297)],
          [(1190, 459), (1352, 459), (1514, 459), (1676, 459)],
          [(1190, 621), (1352, 621), (1514, 621), (1676, 621)],
          [(1190, 783), (1352, 783), (1514, 783), (1676, 783)],
          [(1190, 945), (1352, 945), (1514, 945), (1676, 945)]
          ]
```

И значения матрицы:

```
[[ 77 229   0  59]
 [  0 108 109  33]
 [233 108 233 109]
 [ 77  60 229  72]
 [ 60  33  24 255]
 [255  24  59  72]]
```

Матрица содержит 12 пар значений, то есть каждого элемента по 2.

Задача:

Мне нужно максимально быстро, найти эти 12 пар, и поочередно кликнуть по координатам с помощью  `pyautogui.click(cord)`

Не знаю как лучше и быстрее, сравнивать каждый элемент с каждым, и как только найдено соответствие сразу кликать по координатам соответствующих, или сперва найти все пары и записать координаты в список, в правильном порядке, а потом просто кликнуть по все координатам в списке. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Найти 12 пар где: в матрице или в словаре?

Comment: Akina, звучит круто но ничего не понял

Comment: вася, в словаре

Comment: Не нужно сравнивать координаты, а только значения после координат

Comment: Нет, попытаюсь обьяснить общую задачу. Мне нужно кликнуть по всем парным элементам матрицы, в матрице 24 элемента, но у каждого есть пара, то есть 12 по 2. Что-бы на них кликнуть нужно к каждому значению матрицы привязать координату, куда кликать. Поэтому я создал словарь, который содержит координату, куда кликнуть, и значение, чтобы искать пару.

Comment: Кликать обязательно поочередно, то есть если первый клик был по допустим элементу со значением 56, значит второй обязательно должен быть по элементу со значением 56 тоже.

Comment: Можно без кликов сделать минимальный пример задачи? Пример законченной задачи: мне надо найти в словаре `x` все такие элементы `y`, что `y содержится в z`, далее пример входов `x, y, z` и ожидаемый результат. А то клики, пары, .... постороннему человеку, который не знает ваш код (мне), сложно разобраться

Comment: Извиняюсь, я стараюсь обьяснить что-бы было понятно, не всегда получается.   Так выглядит "ячейка" (не знаю как правильно называется) словаря: (1190, 135): 77. Первые два числа это координаты. Третье число это значение. Так вот эти значения в словаре, нужно сравнить друг с другом. И если находятся два одинаковых значения, то нужно либо записать их координаты в список, либо сразу кликнуть по ним. Но если записывать в список, то нужно исключить повторения, то есть должна быть одна "пара" в списке. Извиняюсь, за непонятное обьяснение, стараюсь как можно понятнее

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать словарь с элементами следующего вида "{значение: [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...]}"? Тогда для всех значений, у которых длина списка больше 1, делайте то что вам надо, остальные игнорируйте

Comment: Извините, не очень понял, но отмечу что матрица каждый раз разная и генерируется совершенно по разному, если этот факт не мешает реализовать ваш способ, можно пожалуйста, коротенький пример используя значения, которые я дал в примере, для наилучшего понимая, заранее спасибо

Comment: У вас словарь с парами "координаты:значение", так? Почему вы не можете изначально хранить другой словарь с парами "значение:список координат для этого значения"? Или преобразовать ваш словарь в этот, если словарь не меняется. По предложенному словарю ваша задача легко решается проходом по каждому значению и проверкой списка координат для этого значения

Comment: Ага, теперь понял, только вопрос, как создать такой словарь, если есть вот такая матрица и список координат, как в примере

Comment: `matrix_cords = {Cords.coords[i][j] : matrix[i][j] for i in range(6) for j in range(4)}`

Comment: Это то как был сделан словарь

Comment: А как сделать словарь который вы предложили, честно не знаю

Comment: Новое значение в матрице => добавляем пару "значение:пустой список" в словарь. Новая координата `coord` пришла для значения `value_for_coord` => добавляем её в список координат для нужного значения `new_dict[value_for_coord].append(coord)`

Comment: Эх, тяжело мне такое дается, можете написать как примерно будет выглядеть цикл?